# Multi Filter of Nested Elasticsearch Data

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
"dictionaryProximities": [
     {
       "proximity": 0.32427,
       "topicDictionaryName": "Electrical",
     },
     {
       "proximity": 0.32141,
       "topicDictionaryName": "Indoor Air Quality",
     },
     {
       "proximity": 0.7321,
       "topicDictionaryName": "Smart Home Technology",
     },
```

I want to create a filter/query that will return all files where the proximity of "Smart Home Technology" is greater than a value, say 0.7.

Right now I have the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "dictionaryProximities",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "dictionaryProximities.topicDictionaryName": {
            "query": "Smart Home Technology",
            "type": "phrase"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

stacked with the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "dictionaryProximities",
      "query": {
        "range": {
          "dictionaryProximities.proximity": {
            "gte": 0.7,
            "lt": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns all files with proximity above 0.7 and contain the name Smart Home Technology. This is very different from what I want, which is all files that have a proximity above 0.7 ONLY for Smart Home Technology.

My question is, is there a way to combine these two queries in a way that achieves the result I want? Is this task even possible since proximity and Name are nested in the same level? Any help would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "dictionaryProximities",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
         "must": [
            {"match": {"dictionaryProximities.topicDictionaryName": "Windows and Doors"}},
            {"range": {"dictionaryProximities.proximity": {"gt": "0.6", "lt": "1.0"}}}
                 ]
          }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```